# JavaScript, Google Maps API and Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to set up a price calculation tool in JS. This is going to calculate amount of kilometers between a set address (business address) and the customer's address, which they can enter into an `<input>` field.

The script will then round off the amount of kilometers to whole euros (no decimals), and display this as the price (charge of this service is 1 euro per kilometer, so no other calculation required to get the price).

So far I came up with the below code. When I enter this into a .html document in notepad, and open that file with Firefox, it works. However, this needs to be implemented on a Wordpress website. 
I put the JS code in the `<head>` and the rest in the `<body>` (as shown below). But for some reason it won't work in Wordpress. (on the Wordpress site, as well as the notepad file, I put the script between `<script>` tags of course)

I tried reading the Wordpress documentation about using JS, and as far as I can see, pasting the code directly into the header is a valid way of making it work (especially for testing purposes) and everything *should* work, but evidently doesn't. I have also used Google, as well as the Stackoverflow search to try and find an answer, but was obviously unsuccessful.

All help would be greatly appreciated!

The website on which it should be, but isn't, working is: http://www.aircostadskanaal.nl/haal-en-breng-service/

The `<head>`:

```
var directionDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var map;

    function initialize() {
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        var melbourne = new google.maps.LatLng(-37.813187, 144.96298);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom:12,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            center: melbourne
        }

    }

    function calcRoute() {
        var start = "Ceresstraat 11, Stadskanaal, Netherlands";
        var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
        var distanceInput = document.getElementById("distance");

        var request = {
            origin:start, 
            destination:end,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };

        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                distanceInput.value = Math.round(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000);
            }
        });
    }
```

The `<body>`:

```
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div>
        <p>
            <!--<label for="start">Start: </label>
            //<input type="text" name="start" id="start" />-->

            <label for="end">Adres: </label>
            <input type="text" name="end" id="end" />

            <input type="submit" value="OK" onclick="calcRoute()" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="distance">Prijs (&euro;): </label>
            <input type="text" name="distance" id="distance" readonly="true" />
        </p>
    </div>
```

edit; removed line to set map as I decided not to include the map on the website. This has not fixed the problem unfortunately.

Comment: Do you get any errors in Console when adding in WordPress? Mostly I will create Custom Page template with own markup and scripts included, and then Apply that template to the custom page in WordPress.

Comment: It's telling me "directionsDisplay is not defined" even though it should be as per the code..   Creating a custom page template may solve the issue, but since this script is likely going to be called from several pages on the website, I'd prefer to include it in the normal header or page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself. Thanks everyone for your input

The issue was `directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();` which was defined as a variable in function `initialize()`, but also used in function `calcRoute()`.

I defined it as a global variable, and now the script works.

Answer (score 0):

The line `map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);` in function `initialize` is referencing element with `id="map_canvas"` but I can't see it in the markup. Did you by any chance forget it?

Comment: Ah, that did display a map at first, but I decided to drop the map because it didn't really add any value for the user. I removed it from the markup, but apparently left it in the code.  -- edit -- removed the line, unfortunately it still doesn't work.